# Не обновляется recycleview с адаптером

Tags: java, android, adapter

Пытаюсь сделать поиск, при изменении edittext обновляю recycleview, но он не хочет обновляться, то есть стирается (обнуляется), а новые записи не появляются, похоже adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class BooksAllFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView empty;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private List<Book> listBook;
    private List<Book> listBookSearch;
    private BookAdapter adapter;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_books_all, container, false);

        empty = view.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        etSearch = view.findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        listBook = getAllAudioFromDevice(getContext());
        listBookSearch = listBook;

        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        adapter = new BookAdapter(getContext(), listBookSearch);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String searchString = s.toString().trim();

                if (searchString.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "пусто", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    listBookSearch.clear();
                    listBookSearch.addAll(listBook);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "не пусто", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    listBookSearch.clear();
                    for (Book book : listBook) {
                        if (book.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Найдено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            listBookSearch.add(book);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        });

        return view;
    }


    // получаем список аудиофайлов в папке "Audiobooks"
    public List<Book> getAllAudioFromDevice(final Context context) {
        final List<Book> tempListBook = new ArrayList<>();

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION
        };

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                projection,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
                new String[]{"%Audiobooks%"}, // адрес папки с аудиокнигами
                null);

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.getCount() == 0)
                empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Book book = new Book();

                String path = c.getString(0); // адрес
                String name = c.getString(1); // название
                String duration = c.getString(2); // продолжительность

                // извлекаем обложку файла
                MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mmr.setDataSource(path);
                byte[] imageBytes = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
                mmr.release();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                if (imageBytes != null)
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length); // берем обложку, если есть
                else
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.no_cover); // ставим стандартную обложку

                book.setPath(path);
                book.setName(name);
                book.setDuration(duration);
                book.setCover(bitmap);

                tempListBook.add(book);
            }
            c.close();
        }

        return tempListBook;
    }

}
```

BookAdapter

```
public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Book> books;
    private Context context;


    public BookAdapter(Context context, List<Book> books) {
        this.context = context;
        this.books = books;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_book, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Book book = books.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(book.getName());
        holder.cover.setImageBitmap(book.getCover());

        long fullTime = Long.valueOf(book.getDuration());
        holder.duration.setText(String.format("%d мин %d сек",
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(fullTime),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(fullTime) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(fullTime)))
        );

        holder.relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("path", book.getPath());
                intent.putExtra("name", book.getName());
                intent.putExtra("duration", book.getDuration());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return books.size();
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView name, duration;
        private ImageView cover;
        private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            duration = view.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            cover = view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
            relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а где у вас ViewHolder?, Также приложите код adapter

Comment: а у вас listBook точно не пустой?

Comment: @danilshik добавил код адаптера. ListBook не пустой, изначально при открытии приложения выводится список, но как только начинаю вводить текст в строке поиска, все пропадает и больше не появляется. Даже если учесть, что ничего не найдено, то при удалении символов все равно должны обратно выводиться все записи

Comment: добавьте метод в adapter для добавления элементов, в котором сначале очищаете arraylist и только потом в него добавляйте, потом принимаете изменения и вызывайте этот метод в активити или фрагменте

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BookAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Book> books;
    private Context context;


    public BookAdapter(Context context, List<Book> books) {
        this.context = context;
        this.books = books;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BookAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_book, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void addData(List<Book> newBooks){
         book.clear();
         book.addAll(newBooks);
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Теперь вызывайте метод addData во фрагменте или активити. Например, участок кода

```
....
    for (Book book : listBook) {
         if (book.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Найдено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                listBookSearch.add(book);
                            }
                        }
    adapter.addData(listBookSearch);
....
```

Проверить не могу, писал прям здесь. Возможно я не прав, и ошибка не в этом

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению, не помогает

Comment: @СергейГуков выложите на git

Comment: Вот https://github.com/bruimafia/FreeAudiobooks

Comment: Вроде сделал, но почему то поиск работает только со второго раза https://yadi.sk/i/yeU2gVy02pHo7Q

Comment: @СергейГуков к сожалению не могу запустить, данные не выводятся, скорее всего базы данных нет.

Comment: @СергейГуков Некоторые рекомендации по коду: у вас есть код
book.setPath(path);
                book.setName(name);
                book.setDuration(duration);
                book.setCover(bitmap);, зачем? у вас же есть конструктор, просто передайте в него эти параметры. Второе: деление по пакетам. Обычно в пакет добавляют все то, что относятся к одному. Например у вас есть что относится к Book (Fragment, Adapter, ViewHolder), они должны лежать в одной месте

Comment: @СергейГуков в AboutFragment вы забыли передать container в inflate в OnCreateView

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое за рекомендации!

Answer (score 0):

В общем не знаю в чем именно проблема, но почему-то не хочет обновлять, если добавлять экземпляр в список методом add. Работает, только если переопределить его.

Было так

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String searchString = s.toString().trim();

        if (searchString.equals("")) {
            listBookSearch.clear();
            listBookSearch = listBook;
            Log.i("Info1",listBookSearch.get(0).getName() + "");
            adapter.addData(listBookSearch);
        } else {
            listBookSearch.clear();
            listBook = getAllAudioFromDevice(getContext());
            Log.i("Info2",listBook.get(0).getName() + "");
            for (Book book : listBook) {
                if (book.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
                    listBookSearch.add(book);
                }
            }
            adapter.addData(listBookSearch);
        }
    }
```

Стало так

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        String searchString = s.toString().trim();

        listBook = getAllAudioFromDevice(getContext());
        listBookSearch.clear();

        if (searchString.length() == 0 || searchString.equals(" "))
            adapter.addData(listBook);
        else {
            for (Book book : listBook) {
                if (book.getName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()))
                    listBookSearch.add(book);
            }

            listBook = listBookSearch;
            adapter.addData(listBook);

            if (listBook.isEmpty())
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "По запросу ничего не найдено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```